# Is it possible to create table with uuid in cassandra?

Tags: python, cassandra, nosql

As title, I want to create a table for my client and they all have a unique uuid created by uuid library. And I use python-driver.

It failed when I want to create table and table name is the uuid string.

```
Ex:

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS 17051a9c-d021-4bd9-97d9-679adff6207 (blk bigint primary key);
```

It shows: `SyntaxException: line1 mismatched character ' ' expecting set null`

Is there any way to solve or I should give up?

Answer (score 1):

We can not create table with name containing -(hyphen/dash).
Refer : [Cassandra table name characteristics](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_using/useCreateTable.html#useCreateTable__tableCharacteristics)

As UUID contains (-) we can not create table name with UUID.

Comment: I tried to remove dash (-) in the UUID string. CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS 17051a9cd0214bd997d9679adff6207...
It shows mismatched character 'd' expecting '-'. Cassandra check the table name if a valid UUID?

Comment: as per documentation table must start with letter..table name from above comment is starting with number..